# form.serialize not working for a list of strings

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, form-submit

I am trying to pass value from the client side to the server side using AJAX. I want to pass the entire model as parameter and so I serialize it and pass it as parameter. However it does not seem to work and no values are found on the server.

The list of string is basically a `select2` dropdown selected values.

This is the simplified code version:

Model :

```
public class FruitsViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListContainer> FruitList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListContainer> VegetableList { get; set; }
    public List<string> SearchFruit { get; set; }
    public List<string> SearchVegetable { get; set; }
}
```

View :

```
<form id="formFruits">

    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SearchFruit , new SelectList(Model.FruitList , "Value", "Display", Model.SearchFruit ), new { @class = "form-control", id = "SearchFruit ", name = "SearchFruit ", multiple = "true" })

    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SearchVegetable , new SelectList(Model.VegetableList , "Value", "Display", Model.SearchVegetable ), new { @class = "form-control", id = "SearchVegetable ", name = "SearchVegetable ", multiple = "true" })

    <button id ='btnSubmit' type='button'>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var page = 4;
var url = "/FruitDetails/Index";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    data: { model: $('#formFruits').serialize(),page:page},
    success: function (result) {
        $("#divResults").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log("Failure!!");
    }
});
});
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FruitsViewModel model,int page)
{
}
```

Is there any issue with the code? Or is it a known problem for Select2 dropdown?

EDIT : I also tried assigning them directly and sending them as JSON string but that does not work either.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var page = 4;
var url = "/FruitDetails/Index";

var SearchFruit = $("#SearchFruit ").val(); 
var SearchVegetable = $("#SearchVegetable").val();

var model = JSON.stringify({
    SearchFruit : SearchFruit,
    SearchVegetable : SearchVegetable
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { model:model, page:page },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#divResults").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log("Failure!!");
    }
});

});
```

That does not seem to work either.

Comment: For the sake of debugging, could you change it to `Index(object model)` and see what it inside `model`?

Comment: It just needs to be `data: $('#formFruits').serialize(),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I had missed out adding a parameter initially. Please check the edited code.

Comment: You cannot use `.serialize()` in a javascript object. Delete `contentType: 'application/json',` and its `data: $('#formFruits').serialize() + '&page=' + page,` (`.serialize()` creates a query string format)

Comment: And the 2nd example does not work because the whole object needs to be stringified, not `model` - `var model = { SearchFruit : SearchFruit, SearchVegetable : SearchVegetable };` (not stringified) and `data: JSON.stringify({ model:model, page:page }),`

Answer (score 0):

The {} are not necessary, delete them, leaving only `data: $ ('#fromFruits').Serialize()` and the form ,do it like this:

> using "Submit" , generally used to validate the form

```js
$( "#formFruits" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  data = $( this ).serialize()
  url = $(this).attr("action")
  
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#Result").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    $("#Result").html("Failure");
    }
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formFruits" action="/action_page.php">

  First input:<br>
  <input type="text" name="input1" required><br>
  
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>

<a> Result: </a>
<a id="Result"> </a>
```

Comment: I need it on a button click, so not quite form submit this.